# FastAPI relationship between two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I'm new to fastAPI and still learning.
I was making two tables which is UserApp and Family, with model and schemas as below:

Model:

```
# AppUser
class AppUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    birth = Column(Integer)
    age = Column(Integer)
    gender = Column(String)
    quest_role = Column(Boolean)
    family_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Families.id'))
    last_login = Column(DateTime)
    createdAt = Column(DateTime)
    updatedAt = Column(DateTime)
    publishedAt = Column(DateTime)

    family = relationship("Family", back_populates="users")

# Families
class Family(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Families'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    createdAt = Column(DateTime)
    updatedAt = Column(DateTime)

    users = relationship("AppUser", back_populates="family")
```

Schemas.py:

```
# =================================Family===========================================
# Create Family Schema (Pydantic Model)
class FamilyCreate(BaseModel):
    name: str
    users: int

# Complete Family Schema (Pydantic Model)
class Family(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    createdAt: datetime = None
    updatedAt: datetime = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# =================================App_User=========================================== 
# Create appUser Schema (Pydantic Model)
class AppUserCreate(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    password: str
    birth: int
    age: int
    gender: str
    quest_role: bool

# Complete appUser Schema (Pydantic Model)
class AppUser(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str
    password: str
    birth: int
    age: int
    gender: str
    quest_role: bool
    family_id: List[Family] = None
    last_login: datetime = None
    createdAt: datetime = None
    updatedAt: datetime = None
    publishedAt: datetime = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Output:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "birth": 0,
    "age": 0,
    "gender": "string",
    "quest_role": true,
    "family_id": null,
    "last_login": "2023-06-23T14:10:34.120964",
    "createdAt": "2023-06-23T14:10:34.120964",
    "updatedAt": "2023-06-23T14:10:34.120964",
    "publishedAt": "2023-06-23T14:10:34.120964"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to make family_id not null and expecting to give me a lists from family table.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "birth": 0,
    "age": 0,
    "gender": "string",
    "quest_role": true,
    "family_id": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z"
      }
    ],
    "last_login": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "createdAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "publishedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z"
  }
]
```

I have tried checking other StackOverflow questions for a solution but I was not able to find a solution or get alot of information to my issue.

Any help with this would be appreciated and if I haven't provided enough information, I am more than willing to provide more.

Comment: Without seeing the code that generates your rwsponse, it’s hard to be sure, but when using Pydantic's `orm_mode`, it matches fields up by name, and `family_id` is your foreign key (i.e. an integer), while `family` is you SQLAlchemy relationship. Try adding `family: Family` to your `AppUser` Pydantic model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you AppUser to following

```
class AppUser(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str
    password: str
    birth: int
    age: int
    gender: str
    quest_role: bool
    family_id: int
    family : Family
    last_login: datetime = None
    createdAt: datetime = None
    updatedAt: datetime = None
    publishedAt: datetime = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

**Output will be :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "birth": 0,
    "age": 0,
    "gender": "string",
    "quest_role": true,
    "family_id": <id>,
    "family": [
      {
        
        "name": "string",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z"
      }
    ],
    "last_login": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "createdAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z",
    "publishedAt": "2023-06-23T06:56:22.730Z"
  }
]
```

**Hope this helps!**